# "Mi piacciono fare riferimenti automobilistici"?

Tags: verbs, grammar

1. Mi piacciono fare riferimenti automobilistici o mi piace fare riferimenti automobilistici.
2. Le cose che mi piacciono fare o che mi piace fare.

Io direi che la versione al singolare è quella corretta, visto che il soggetto è la proposizione soggettiva implicita, ma leggendo un articolo, mi sono imbattuto nella frase che mi sta destando questi dubbi, ovvero quella da titolo.

Voi che ne pensate?

Grazie mille a chi risponderà.

Comment: “Non mi piacciono i riferimenti automobilistici, mi piace invece fare i salti mortali”. ;-)

Comment: Puoi dire dove hai letto quella frase?

Comment: Certo, hai ragione tu: è un palese refuso, neppure una questione di grammatica. Qualcuno avrà scritto “Mi piacciono i riferimenti automobilistici” e poi avrà modificato la frase ma dimenticandosi di aggiornare il verbo.

Comment: @Hachi Sembra l'abbia detta [Ditonellapiaga](https://www.rollingstone.it/musica/interviste-musica/ditonellapiaga-ti-prende-a-morsi/559207/)

Answer (score 5):

Hai senz'altro ragione: “mi piace” richiede un soggetto singolare, “mi piacciono” uno plurale.

*“Mi piacciono fare riferimenti automobilistici” è un palese refuso, neppure una questione di grammatica. Qualcuno avrà scritto “Mi piacciono i riferimenti automobilistici” e poi avrà modificato la frase ma dimenticandosi di aggiornare il verbo.

Comment: possiamo quindi dire definitivamente  che è scorretta anche grammaticalmente, essendo che il soggetto è singolare ed è "fare i riferimenti automobilistici"?

Comment: Esattamente, @Maxim.